# Is there a way to create app folders that user can access without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Android?

Tags: android

My app reads users' text files as input and do some stuff according to them. Currently it's done by setting MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but this permission is excessive as I don't access anything else.

I've been searching on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage but have yet to come up with any good ideas. Is there any suggested manner to do so? Thanks :)

Comment: you will probably need to migrate to storage access framework, it is less permissive than the permission you are currently using and it allows to read entire user folders and files (although is the user that chose which folder you can read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shall help: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

(Though I'm not sure if your file type is supported.)